# Why qmake passes -Wl,O1 to gcc when linking and will it harm LTO?

Tags: gcc, qmake

I noticed that in the default release configuration, qmake (qmake 3.1, qt 5.9.5 - whatever is installed on my Ubuntu build box) passes `-Wl,O1` to g++ when linking. So the linking command line looks like

```
g++ -Wl,-O1 -flto -O2 -o program program.o lib1.a lib2.a ...
```

where `-flto -O2` are the options that I'm passing via `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE` to enable LTO.

Now the question: why qmake has this `-Wl,-O1` option and is it going to interfere with LTO?

Answer (score 1):

QMake passes -Wl,O1, because it is meant to be a good default.

It will not harm LTO, because your -O2 option comes later and overrides the -Wl,O1.

From g++'s man page:

> If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the
>   last such option is the one that is effective.

You can remove the -Wl,-O1 from your Makefile by specifying

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Wl,-O1
```